# Position div behind overlapping div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've got the following setup http://jsfiddle.net/47x60k4w/529/.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
header
</div>
<div class="inner_block">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="xxx" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="xxx" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="xxx" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
footer
</div>
```

The `inner_block` should overlap the `header` class and the footer should be placed right behind the `inner_block`.

In my solution I just don't get the footer behind the `inner_block` without doing not responsible stuff like calling a `margin-top` with x.xem on it. I just found some links with `z-index` stuff which didn't worked for me because the `inner_block` lost his passed height and width from the nested block.

The result should look like this beautiful mockup.
[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean your footer should come after inner block? Can you make a sketch/drawing of the result you want, please?

Comment: Did you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/denea/47x60k4w/530/ ?

Comment: Yeas @DeneaNovac i meant it like in your second post and i got the same result ealier. But as i described, the inner_blocks inherited width and height got destroyed.

Comment: @user2742409 check out the solution and the alternate `flexbox` solution  that I have added to my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made the following changes to your code:

1. Remove the `position: absolute` for the `inner-block`.
2. As you are floating the contents of the `inner-block` you have `clear` the `float`s *so that the parent container will not lose height*.

   ```
   .inner_block:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     clear: both;
   }
   ```

   Whenever using floats, remember to `clear` it.
3. Added `position: relative` to the `inner_block` to position it over the `header` and `footer`.
4. Added `display: block` to the `img` so that you can remove the small space below it characteristic on `inline` elements (the default display).
5. Also tinkered a bit with the margins and widths to achieve the layout.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.inner_block {
  position: relative;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: -2.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  background-color: white;
}
.inner_block:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.column {
  max-width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.column:first-child{
    margin-left: 2.5%;
 }
.column:last-child{
    margin-left: 0;
 }
.column img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="inner_block">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088605.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088607.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088606.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  test
</div>
```

Hope this gives you a head-start. Check it out and let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

**Alternate Solution**:

So here is a solution using a `flexbox` which is easier to set up:

First remove the `float`ing container and the clearfix.

Now Wrap the `inner_block` with another div

```
.inner_block_wrapper {
  margin: -2.5% 2.5% 2.5% 2.5%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.inner_block {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.column {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Using `display: flex` allows the images to take the available space along the row and `justify-content: center` aligns it along the center. Check this out!

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.inner_block_wrapper {
  margin: -2.5% 2.5% 2.5% 2.5%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.inner_block {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.column {
  margin: 5px;
}
.column img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="inner_block_wrapper">
  <div class=" inner_block ">
    <div class="column ">
      <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088605.jpg " />
    </div>
    <div class="column ">
      <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088607.jpg " />
    </div>
    <div class="column ">
      <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088606.jpg " />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer ">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: @user2742409 check out the solution and the alternate `flexbox` solution above...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on my code and the really nice alternative, it really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can even try something as below, your codes were fine just set your `.footer margin-top` equal to the `height` of `.header` and `.inner_block` using `css calc() function`.

```css
.header{
  position:relative;
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.footer{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  margin-top:calc(100% - 82%);
}

.inner_block{
  position: absolute;
  width:90%;
  border:solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color:white;
  margin:-2.5% calc(100% - 97%);
}

.column {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1.6%;
}

.column img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
  
  </div>
  <div class="inner_block">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088605.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088607.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <img src="http://www.healthytravellovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/photo233227749810088606.jpg" />
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="footer">
    test
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you were looking for ?

```
.header{
  position:relative;
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.footer{
  clear:both;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.inner_block{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top:-2.5%;
  background-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8y4e8L08/

Comment: Its not what i was looking for because the inner_blocks size got destroyed but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well just using the z-index won't always work. You also need to specify the 'position' property as well so as to define the z-index wrt some position of the frame.

Z-index is a property which defines the 'depth' or 'height' of an element. If your `<header>` has z-index of  '100' and;  `<div>` element defined inside the header, usually it would be shown above it but once you define the z-index:50; since 50<100, `<div>` element would be hidden behind it.

Example of z-index

1) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

2) https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .header {
        height: 200px;
        width:800px; 
        background-color:#000;
        margin:20px;
    }
   .header {
        margin-bottom: -25px;
    }
    .inner_block {
        width: 35%; 
        height: 150px;
        margin: auto 200px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        border:1px solid #000;
        margin-top: -45px; 

    }
    .column{
        max-width:20%;
        float:left;
        border: 2px soid #999;
        margin:25px;  
    }
    .column img{
         max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        }

    .footer {
        height: 100px; 
        margin-top: -25px;
        margin:20px;
        background-color:#F00;
        width:800px;

    }
    .content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

---

```
 <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="inner_block">
     <div class="column">
       <img src="download.jpg"/>
        </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="download.jpg"/>
       </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="download.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </div> 
<div class="footer">
</div>
```